# How do i get data from firebase database without listeners javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have some silly qestion to ask please.
So when a client click button "buy" database has to add clients email into some child "foodGuide",but before it has to check if the email is not in the database yet. Methods .on() or .once() called only when database changes,however i need to retrive data without any changes in database.
this is my code:

function addToDataBase() {

```
    var user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var isInDB = false;
    var database = firebase.database();
    var ref = database.ref("foodGuide");
    ref.on('value',function(snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach(function(element){
                if (user.email == element.child("email").val()){
                    isInDB = true;              
                }
            })
    });
    if(isInDB== false){
    var data = {
        email: user.email,
        guide: true
        }
    
    ref.push(data);
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do this(exept making changes in db everytime u need a snapshot,and deleting it in call back function),but it is easy to do this in firestore database!
function addToDataBase() {

```
    var user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var docRef = db.collection("foodGuide").doc(user.email);
    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("bought");
    } else {
        db.collection("foodGuide").doc(user.email).set({
            bought:true
        }).then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("added");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
    
    
}
```